# Boundary sensitive Cmd+D in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on OSX.

Using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, I want to select the next instance of `es` but not if it's part of another word

Given this code

[image: my code]

I select the first instance of `es` and see this

[image: initial selection]

Perfect! However, when I tap <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> a couple times, it will end up selecting this

[image: annoying]

Super annoying!

How can I make <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> only select the highlighted sections that appear in image 2?

Comment: It's acting as intended. Do not select the word (via mouse or some expand selection command) before hitting `cmd+d`. Instead, with the cursor over the word, hit `cmd+d` as many times as necessary. This should respect word boundaries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you select whole word and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> it is going to select like in 3rd image. If you put your cursor (caret) on the word but not select it and then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> it is going to select like in 2nd image.

For Windows just change <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: how to do in windows?cursor has to select a word

Comment: @Mithril I'm not sure what you are asking but I updated my answer to also include Windows shortcut.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760021/boundary-sensitive-ctrld-in-sublime-text-3windows

Answer (score 0):

It works as in image 2 by default, at least for me. Do you have the following key mapping?

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand"},...
```

You could also try [reverting to a freshly installed state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html).

Comment: I actually don't have any custom key mappings set up. Where would I define this?

Comment: @maček: Custom keymaps can be set in Preferences -> Key Bindings - User. Although you could just check that the mentioned mapping exists in Key Bindings - Default first.

Comment: I tried both `["cmd+d"]` and `["ctrl+d"]` and neither are giving the expected behavior

Comment: Do you have any additional packages installed? Maybe you could try disabling them and see what happens?

Comment: I found this in my default key map `{ "keys": ["super+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" }`. I don't have any other plugins installed and I'm still getting the behavior I described in my question.

Comment: Try replacing `"super+d"` with `"cmd+d"` (or "ctrl+d", not sure how things work with Mac) in your default key map file.