# Boundary sensitive Ctrl+D in Sublime Text 3(windows)

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have same requirement with [maček](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776999/boundary-sensitive-cmdd-in-sublime-text)

I borrow maček's example here:

my code `pic1`:

[image: my code]

I select the first instance of `es` and see this (using cursor select)

`pic2`:

[image: initial selection]

Perfect! However, when I tap <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> a couple times, it will end up selecting this

`pic3`:

[image: annoying]

The answer from Taylan says

> If you put your cursor (caret) on the word but not select it and then press Cmd + d it is going to select like in 2nd image.

Quite confusing.
In windows, there is always a `input cursor`(a flashing vertical line, maybe call as caret) in sublime, Without selecting any thing type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> would select the char nearby the `input cursor`. Can't not get the result as `pic2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is from Sublime Text 3 ([Build 3095](https://sublimetext.com/3dev)) on Windows 7. The behavior is exactly the same on OS X and Linux, and on other builds.

First, we enter the text and place the cursor anywhere by the first word in the string, `es`:

```ruby
test 'es cookie set on .test' do
#    ^^^ anywhere here
```

It can be before the `e`, between the `e` and the `s`, or after the `s` - it doesn't matter.

[image]

Next, without double-clicking, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, which selects `es` and highlights the other instances of the word.

[image]

Now, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> twice more, and only the *individual* instances of `es` will be selected, not those that are contained within other words, such as `test`:

[image]

---

Now, if you were to double-click or otherwise select the first instance of `es` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> several times, this would be the result:

[image]

*Every* instance of `es` will be selected, even when within another word such as `test` or `cookies`.

What I've described is the default behavior of Sublime Text on all platforms, including Windows. If you put your cursor in a word and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, the whole word should be selected. If that does not happen, then somehow the key binding has been changed, either by a plugin or in your user keybindings file.

Comment: Thank you! I mistake Taylan 's answer, I though it was putting my `mouse cursor icon` over the word , then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (obviously wouldn't work), didn't realize it just need put `input cursor` nearby the word !